# How do i write a shell script so that when i compile my c++ program it will put the binary into the Binary Directory

Tags: shell, binary, g++, compiler

I have a directory called `Binary` and bunch of source files:

```
./
├── Binary/
├── lesson02.cpp
├── lesson04.cpp
└── lesson06.cpp
```

when I compile the source code

```
g++ lesson01.cpp -o lesson01
```

I want `lesson01` to be placed in `Binary/`

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use a shell script for this. The correct answer is to change the argument you pass to `-o` in the compile command to include the directory. E.g.: `g++ lesson01.cxx -o Binary/lesson01`

Comment: @HalosGhost you may as well post that as an answer so the OP can accept it and the question be marked as answered.

Comment: I didn't feel it merited an answer since it was explicitly denying the OP's premise. But, @derobert captured the gist of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell scripts are very similar to the commands you'd type interactively in the shell. In this case, the `-o` option is telling `g++` where to put the binary. So you just tell it you want it in the binary directory:

```
g++ lesson01.cpp -o Binary/lesson01
```

You can run that interactively (by typing it into the shell), or you can put that in a shell script—both will do the same thing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
g++ lesson01.cpp -o Binary/lesson01
```

Normally, however, you'd use a Makefile to do things like this, not a shell script.

```make
all:

Binary/%: %.cpp
    g++ -o "$@" "$<"  # Note: this must be a tab, not spaces. Make is annoying like that
```

then you'd type `make Binary/lesson01` and Make would compile the program (if the source is newer than the existing binary, or if the binary doesn't exist). You can also list all the programs after that `all:` up top (`all: Binary/lesson01 Binary/lesson02`, etc.) and then just typing `make` will compile all the programs as needed.

You can also do more advanced things with Make or a shell script (for example, to have it determine the list of programs to compile, instead of you listing them all) but that's a fair bit more complicated.

Comment: +1 for GNU `make`: [Oh, The Places You'll Go!](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) :D